# Save numpy array in SVG format

Tags: python, image, numpy, svg

I have an image which I want to save in svg format.
The image is in the form of a numpy array.
Although, there exist many methods to save array in different image formats, I could not find the one which says it could be done in svg.

Any pointers or python script would be great!

Thanks

Comment: How can an array represent a scalable vector graphic?

Comment: you can use matplotlib, : `pl.imshow(array); pl.savefig("test.svg");`, but It doesn't convert the image to vector graph,

Comment: @KSFT, Like we convert an image to svg or embed an image in svg!

Comment: What you're asking for does not make a lot of sense. If the image already consists of an array of pixel values then it is fundamentally in a [raster format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics). You *can* embed a raster image within an SVG container, but there is no magic way to convert a raster image to a [vector representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics).

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is in a raster format, the best you can do is to convert it to vector graphics with some program like [potrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potrace). It has python bindings [pypotrace](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypotrace).

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import potrace

# Make a numpy array with a rectangle in the middle
data = np.zeros((32, 32), np.uint32)
data[8:32-8, 8:32-8] = 1

# Create a bitmap from the array
bmp = potrace.Bitmap(data)

# Trace the bitmap to a path
path = bmp.trace()

# Iterate over path curves
for curve in path:
    print "start_point =", curve.start_point
    for segment in curve:
        print segment
        end_point_x, end_point_y = segment.end_point
        if segment.is_corner:
            c_x, c_y = segment.c
        else:
            c1_x, c1_y = segment.c1
            c2_x, c2_y = segment.c2
```