# Convert numpy array image to svg format image

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, bitmap, vectorization

I have a numpy image, the dimension is 600*600*4, since it is a RGBA format image.
I want to save the numpy image to svg format, is there any way to achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639819/converting-numpy-array-svg-image>?

Comment: A quick google search yielded the result in the above comment. I recommend you try and do at least a small amount of research before asking your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I read the post before, the problem is pypotrace is not available for my python version...